# Get the Monday of this week where a week is Mon - Sun (VBScript)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

In VBScript, how can I get the Monday of the current week, assuming a week is Mon-Sun and **not** Sun-Sat?

The following code returns the Monday when a week is Sun-Sat, so it's close but not quite right:

```
Private Function getMonday(d)
    getMonday = DATEADD("d", 2 - WEEKDAY(d), d)
End Function
```

How can I do this without changing any LCID settings?

Comment: what exactly are you passing to the function which gets represented by 'd'?

Comment: A date, eg today's Date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weekday takes a second argument to specify the first day of the week.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t51x9wtx(v=vs.84).aspx

So `DateAdd("d", 1 - WeekDay(d, 2), d)`

I didn't test this to make sure my logic is correct.  But the technique should work for you.